# using destructors in c++ to delete pointers

Tags: visual-c++, destructor

I have the following:

```
//in Matrix.h
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix (int _row1=1, int  _col1=1);
    Matrix(const Matrix &);
    ~Matrix();

    int row1;
    //int row2;
    int col1;
    double **m;
    //other functions and members...
    void Print(int id);

}

//In Matrix.cpp
Matrix::Matrix(int _row1, int  _col1): row1(_row1),col1(_col1)
{
    m=(double **) new double[row1];
    for(long p=0;p<row1;p++) m[p]=(double *) new double[col1];
    for(long p=0;p<row1;p++) for (long q=0;q<col1;q++) m[p][q]=0.0;
}


//copy constructor
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &Mat){

    m=(double **) new double[row1];
    **m=**Mat.m;// copy the value
}
// Destructor
Matrix::~Matrix(void){
     //We need to deallocate our buffer
    delete[] *m;
    delete [] m;
     //Set m to null just in case
    m=0;
    cout<<" Freeing m "<<endl;
}
void Matrix::Print(int id)
{
cout<<"Element ID: "<<id<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<row1; i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<col1;j++) {
        cout<<m[i][j];
        if(j==col1-1) cout<<"\n";
    }
}
system("PAUSE");
}
```

a call like the following:

```
elem[e].d0 = matel[i].OrgD;// Both Matrix
elem[e].d0.Print(1); // checking to see if at all copied
```

fails at:

```
void Matrix::Print(int id){
//...
 cout<<m[i][j];//here
...//
}
```

in fact it fails where ever m[i][j] is used by other functions.
this only happens if any object is used successively. And this error goes away if I comment
out the destructor. I fail to understand? Any help!

EDIT 1: I have changed the copy constructor to:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &Mat):row1(Mat.row1),col1(Mat.col1)
{
 m= new double *[row1];
 for(long p=0;p<row1;p++) m[p]=new double [col1];
 for(long p=0;p<row1;p++)for (long q=0;q<col1;q++) m[p][q]=Mat.m[p][q];
    // copy   the Value
}
```

And have a  assignment operator as:

```
Matrix& Matrix::operator = (const Matrix& o) {
  if ( this == &o ) {
    return *this; //Self assignment : nothing to do
}

delete[] *m;
delete[] m;

row1 = o.row1;
col1 = o.col1;
m = new double*[row1];
for(long p=0;p<row1;p++) m[p]=new double [col1];

for(long p=0;p<row1;p++) for (long q=0;q<col1;q++) m[p][q]=o.m[p][q];

return *this;
}
```

Now it fails at:

```
Matrix::Operator=...
  {
    o.m[p]  0xcdcdcdcd  double *
    CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated  // in the debugger

  }
```

I have noticed that the same thing happens form all functions that use '.m' that is m of the calling object is not available if there is the destructor deleting 'm'. Hope to get some answers.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you are using

```
m=(double **) new double[row1];
for(long p=0;p<row1;p++) m[p]=(double *) new double[col1];
```

`new double[row1]` is of type `double[]`. You cast this to `double**`. You should use `new (double*)[row1]` here if you really want to get an array of double pointers.

Comment: if you use `m[i][j]` this is interpreted as `(m[i])[j]` which is `(m + i * sizeof(double)) + j * sizeof(double)`. Depending on your architecture this *may* work, but generally you can not assume, that `sizeof(double *) == sizeof(double)`. I think, m[0][0] should always work, because the sizeof will not matter in this case.

Comment: Ok so I have changed `m=(double **) new (double)[row1];
 for(long p=0;p<row1;p++) m[p]=(double *) new double[col1];` to `m= new double *[row1];
  for(long p=0;p<row1;p++) m[p]=new double [col1];` but that doesnt solve my problem!!

Comment: Ok, the problem seems to be your copy constructor which does strange things. It allocates some memory (not enough to hold the whole matrix, just one row) and then copies just one value (the first one). Does it only fail if you copy a matrix?

Comment: By the way: It would be a great idea to allocate subsequent memory for the matrix (`new double[row * col]`)...

Comment: where do i add the code for allocating subsequent memory. No it always fails.(i.e if i comment out the copy constructor)

Comment: If you comment out the copy constructor, it will be created automatically by the compiler and will behave very similar and simply copy the pointer so that two instances have the same data area. If the destructor of one copy is called the memory is freed and other instances have a pointer to unallocated memory resulting in a segfault. Solution: Always implement a copy constructor if the constructor allocates memory (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)